# What is the use of count in stackdriver metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a log metric that is like this:

```
description: hangup
filter: |-
  resource.type="global"
  jsonPayload.message="hanged up"
labelExtractors:
  campaign: EXTRACT(jsonPayload.context.campaignId)
  causa: EXTRACT(jsonPayload.context.attempt.hangupCause)
  pickedUp: EXTRACT(jsonPayload.context.pickedUp)
metricDescriptor:
  description: hangup
  labels:
  - description: causa de colgado
    key: causa
    valueType: INT64
  - description: "campa\xF1a"
    key: campaign
    valueType: INT64
  - key: pickedUp
    valueType: BOOL
  metricKind: DELTA
  name: projects/redacted/metricDescriptors/logging.googleapis.com/user/hangupcause
  type: logging.googleapis.com/user/hangupcause
  unit: '1'
  valueType: INT64
name: hangupcause
```

If I do an aggregation/alignment by SUM it does what I expect in an aggregation by count:

[image: SUM]

IF I do COUNT for example in ALIGNMENT/AGGREGATION :

[image: COUNT]

I want to understand  what is the use of the COUNT function in alignment and aggregation? What are we counting or summing ?

Comment: I don't know about StackDriver specifically, but normally when you do this aggregation for metrics to compute average or stddev you need `sum(values)/sum(counts)` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GCP, “count in aggregation” is the active number of metrics running at that particular time. For example, in your diagram, the red line is describing that for that particular group you are monitoring, there are four active metrics running.